# Вернуть ошибку в виде json

Tags: symfony

Есть аннотация в symfony 4, которая разрешает только `POST` запросы, если был отправлен не `POST` запрос, то появляется стандартная ошибка symfony. Как я могу отловить эту ошибку, чтобы вернуть ее в виде `json`?

```
 `/**
 * @Route("/add_user", name="add_user", methods="POST")
 */`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать слушателя событий и слушать `kernel.exception`

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;

class CustomExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();

        if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            $response = new JsonResponse('custom error ');
            $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
            $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
        }else{
            return;
        }

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

И затем зарегистрировать этого слушателя в `service.yaml`

```
App\EventListener\CustomExceptionListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Вот ещё [ссылка](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) на документацию.

Будут вопросы - задавайте.